# How does the Shrine of the Gunbringer work?

Tags: borderlands-2

I came across the Shrine of the Gunbringer where it looks like I can sacrifice something or someone it the main chamber.... How does it work and how can I use it?  I saw a video of it [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z31L38D0Xeg) but when I tried jumping in it & having my friend hit the lever, it didn't do anything.  Is there any criteria that has to be met to use it?

[image]

Some of the comments on YouTube Suggest the following:

> Step 1. Go to the shrine.
>
> Step 2. Make SURE no person presses the button early or it will be wasted. This has happened multiple times for me. People run up and press the button. The light should be green on the button. If it is red, someone was an idiot.
>
> Step 3. Have all of your sacrifices get in the hole.
>
> Step 4. Sacrificed them and wait.

Can anyone confirm or deny these suggestions?

Sorta spoiler below:

> I just completed the Rescue Roland quest.

Tried the button and it did not work.

Comment: You waited til they respawned, right? Absolutely nothing?

Comment: I was about to ask the same question :(.  I would note that the text he says when you fail is "You gotta give me something to work with".  I assume it is for sacrificing people, but I don't know who or how.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've used the shrine with my brother in co-op and can confirm that it works with putting players in the pit.

Firstly, you only get one lever pull when the zone loads, so it's important not to pull it before your sacrifice is in. Once they are in, pull the lever, and the top shuts. Flames turn on inside the pit and the sacrifice (slowly) dies. Once they die, the shrine provides some loot.

We did this around level 15 on the first playthrough, and the loot wasn't very good. I would be interested to know if the loot gets better on playthrough 2 or by putting more players in the pit. I'm not sure if this works on NPCs, if you could even manage to get one in there!

Comment: This is correct; myself and some friends tried it. I think the goods are better the more people get killified, but we never tested again.

Comment: Confirmed: You have to go back there to use it again (reload the area / game ).  Putting any weapons in there doesnt do anything.  In fact they just sit there at the bottom lol.  We were able to get back the weapons we threw in there by crouching on the closed hatch.  I wonder if you can get some nice weapons with a full party?

Comment: It does work. You get better rewards if the people who are sacrificed are high leveled.

Answer (score 0):

if have the assasin you can run your holograph in that direction.  If timed right a baddie will run up into the hole as you press the lever
.

Answer (score -4):

I think you also need to drop a weapons and items in there with the people. It will take them and gives you just a few better weapons back.

Comment: Weapons do not matter to the loot given back, Just tested this a few times.  Just the people have to get in the hole before hitting the sacrifice lever