# Is there any reason to sacrifice myself?

Tags: borderlands-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the Shrine of the Gunbringer work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/86118/how-does-the-shrine-of-the-gunbringer-work)

Behind the W4R-D3N under Marcus' Shrine is a little pit with a button next to it. If you push the button the pit closes and doesn't open again. I'm guessing this is used in co-op since I can't activate it while I'm in the pit.

Is this used for anything in particular or is it just a decoration of sorts and for fun?

Comment: damn, two duplicate questions in one day. I'm losing it

Comment: Don't get discouraged! Our search and "related questions" are both terrible. Duplicates are bound to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you sacrifice yourself, the Marcus shrine will yield a random rare weapon and some money.

It is easiest to do this in co-op, although you can do it in single player if you manage to lure a bandit into the hole. Note however that you can only do this one time per level - even if you accidentally close the pit when no one is inside of it, you don't get a chance to redo the sacrifice and will have to exit and re-enter the area.

Comment: Once per playthrough or once per time the level is loaded?

Comment: @DomenikVanBuskirk once per time the level is loaded. I'll edit my answer to be clearer.